# Write but not delete

Tags: permissions, access-control-list, glusterfs

We are using glusterfs for our cloud storage needs. Since the partition is open to many servers, we would like to disable file deletion as we don't delete or overwrite any file.

Glusterfs does not have ACL, so I need to implement this solution outside of the glusterfs. Perhaps I can mount the disks read and write only (with disabling deletion), but could not find any solution. Setfacl etc. does not work on the partition.

How can we disable file deletion -at least- on the client machines?

Answer (score 1):

File deletion requires write access to the directory.  Try disabling write access to the directory.

Warning:  This will also prevent file creation.  It is only appropriate for fully populated directories.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using linux/unix server it is possible by setting below sticky bit to the folder.

chmod +t folder

This will allow any user to write in the directory and cannot delete the folder.

Regards,

S.Ragavendra Ganesh